# apache cordova browser compatibility

Tags: cordova, browser

I have a trouble. I just paid attention, that my cordova app does not work fine on some devices. To my mind, it happens on devices where is no default android browser, but there is a specific one instead: Xiaomi MIUI and Samsung TouchWIZ(last version). In such case, my app makes "freeze". On many other devices it works fine. Cordova version is 6.1.1. So, what can I do with this?

My app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ua.aviatur.aviatourapp

Comment: Why don't you use InAppBrowser instead ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at the Xwalk project. https://crosswalk-project.org/.

The idea is to embed the browser in your cordova app so you don't depend on whatever has been (randomly) installed as browser by the various manufacturers using android as OS.

Comment: Use the Crosswalk WebView. Here are the instructions to install it via cordova:  https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview